# Using Array_contruct to sort a column of arrays with a stored procedure after it was created

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I came across a thread to sort, when I was trying to find a solution to sort my column of array.

I tried the answer and am having trouble with setting a variable to store an array.

This does not work:

```
SET b = ['asdfk', 'sdfdd'];
```

This is what I tried:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sort_func(a array)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
  return A.reverse()
$$
;

 SELECT sort_func('foo');
```

Where SELECT sort_func('foo');

This is the error:

```sql
SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 7 Invalid argument types for function 'SORT_FUNC': (VARCHAR(3))
```

May I please have some help better understanding how Snowflake see 'arrays'.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a bunch of stuff at issue here:

1. The function is expecting an array in and passing a string back, but nothing in the function does that casting.
2. The select on the function is with a string, not an array, so the function is expecting an array and getting a string.

Try something like this to mimic the reverse() JS function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SORT_FUNC(V array)
  RETURNS array
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
   if (V !== null) {
        return V.reverse();
      }
$$;

SELECT sort_func( array_construct('foo','bar') );
```

Comment: It makes sense that the passing of a string would not work, thank you I modified it to also include the "arracy_construct" cast on the data as well.

Answer (score 0):

This operation could be achieved with [ARRAY_SORT](https://docs.snowflake.com/sql-reference/functions/array_sort):

```
SELECT *, ARRAY_SORT(arr, FALSE)
FROM tab;
```

For input:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(arr ARRAY) AS
SELECT ['asdfk', 'sdfdd']
UNION ALL SELECT [10, 30, 20];
```

Output:

[image]

---

As the time of writing  `ARRAY_SORT(input_array, sort_ascending, nulls_first)` is present but not enabled by default:

```
SHOW FUNCTIONS LIKE 'ARRAY_SORT%';

ARRAY_SORT(ARRAY [, BOOLEAN] [, BOOLEAN]) RETURN ARRAY  the sorted array
```

[2023_05 Bundle (Disabled by Default)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/bcr-bundles/2023_05_bundle)

```
SELECT SYSTEM$ENABLE_BEHAVIOR_CHANGE_BUNDLE('2023_05');
```