# Snowflake/SQL: How to compare 2 tables data (rows), when they have (non-deterministic) transformations?

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to compare the data stored in two tables (say *table1* and *table2*), where both tables have the exact same columns.

I tried to use the following SQL code snippet

```
SELECT *
FROM table1

minus 

SELECT *
FROM table2
```

However, when I want to compare tables where one of the columns is a result of a non-deterministic function/transformation (see for example: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_unique_agg), this approach doesn't work.

The values produced by this transformation are always the same, but the order in which they arrange the items are not always the same, and thus the above snippet does not compare the tables properly.

--
I expected this to produce no query results, but instead I got a table with some rows that appear to be different, but are actually the same (they only differ in one of the columns that was built using the non-deterministic function/transformation as explained before).

Is there a way I can compare both tables using a similar approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to compare tables would be sorting arrays before comparison:

```
SELECT * REPLACE(ARRAY_SORT(arr_col) AS arr_col)
FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT * REPLACE(ARRAY_SORT(arr_col) AS arr_col)
FROM table2;
```

---

Example:

```
SELECT * REPLACE(ARRAY_SORT(arr_col) AS arr_col)
FROM (SELECT 1 AS id, [1,2,3] AS arr_col) 
EXCEPT
SELECT * REPLACE(ARRAY_SORT(arr_col) AS arr_col)
FROM (SELECT 1 AS id, [3,2,1] AS arr_col);
-- 0 rows
```

---

Related:

- [ARRAY_SORT](https://docs.snowflake.com/sql-reference/functions/array_sort)
- [Using Array_contruct to sort a column of arrays with a stored procedure after it was created](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76690066/5070879)
- [SELECT * REPLACE(...)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/select)

Comment: This was very useful!

( P.S.: If you upvote my question I would have enough reputation to upvote your answer, so please help me help you)